# Cant launch IntelliJ on OSX-yesomite

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm, osx-yosemite

I upgraded my machine few days back. I am trying to launch IntelliJ however I get this message

[image]

I changed the JVM Version in Info.plist to 1.8*

`<key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.8*</string>`

Still I was not able to launch IntelliJ

Any workaround?

Comment: Anything in the IJ log? I suppose it should be in your user's home dir under `.IntelliJIdea14/system/log`.

Comment: I cannot find this file in my home dir

Comment: My bad, I assumed it's similar to windows. A quick search [revealed](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) that on MacOSX they should be under `~/Library/Logs/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`. Can you please recheck?

Comment: CoreSimulator
CrashReporter
DeviceLink
DiagnosticReports
FaceTime
GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.log
Handoff
Homebrew
ProtectedCloudStorage-20150329120301-SignIn.log
SMSMigrator
SparkleUpdateLog.log
Sync
TeamViewer
Ubiquity
com.apple.NotesMigratorService
com.citrixonline.GoToMeeting
com.citrixonline.WebDeployment
fsck_hfs.log
pip
talagent.log

These are the files that i see inside my Library/Logs/